# Unable to implement Comparable interface on Kotlin Enum

Tags: kotlin, enums, comparable

I would like my Enum values to be comparable with other types, for instance, `String`. I am not entirely sure why it complains and what the error means.

```
enum class Fruits(val value: String): Comparable<String>{
    Apple("apple"),
    Orange("orange");

    override fun compareTo(other: String): Int {
        return compareValuesBy(this.value, other)
    }
}

val test: Boolean = Fruits.Apple == "apple"
```

Error says:

```
Type parameter T of 'Comparable' has inconsistent values: Fruits, String
```

Comment: There are two issues, the major one is that `compareTo` is final in `Enum` so you may have to rethink your approach. The other one is that you need `Comparable<Fruits>` rather then `Comparable<String>`

Comment: Also, implementing Comparable doesn't modify the implementation of `==`. That's managed by the `equals` function. But the contract for `equals` is that it must be reflexive. Since you cannot modify the `String.equals()` function, you cannot safely do this.

Comment: @Tenfour04 oh yeah, you are completely correct. I think I had a brain-fart.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps sealed classes are better suited to implement comparable enum, something like:

```kotlin
sealed class Fruit(val name: String) : Comparable<Fruit> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Fruit): Int = this.name.compareTo(other.name)
}

data object Apple    : Fruit("apple")
data object Orange   : Fruit("orange")
data object Zucchini : Fruit("zucchini")

fun main() {
    println(Apple < Orange)    // true
    println(Orange < Zucchini) // true
}
```

Comment: I think I was more looking for equality of different data types. ie. equality between an enum and a string

Comment: I guess that is slightly different, you can start with `Comparable<Any>` / `compareTo(other: Any)` and see how it goes.